# Вытащить значение ячейки не виде даты

Tags: google-apps-script

Как вытащить зачине из ячейки не в виде даты, если значение ячейки = 10-07-82360
var num = sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
получаю значение: Sat Jul 09 82360 17:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),

а хочу чтобы было "10-07-82360" и потом его обратно вписать в виде текста, что бы excel при импорте не воспринимал значение как дату.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getValue() замените на getDisplayValue() и получите значение как в таблице

Comment: Спасибо, отлично работает, только так и не могу преобразовать полученное значение для корректной выгрузки для excel - всё равно импортируется как дата.

Answer (score 0):

"Обмануть" excel удалось с помощью апострофа:

var zavnomer = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getDisplayValue();
var zavnomer = ("'" + zavnomer);

не уверен, что это лучшее решение.
Пока использую его, если есть более красивое прошу помочь.
Спасибо.